# Awk replace a column with its hash value

Tags: shell, sed, awk

How can I replace a column with its hash value (like MD5) in awk or sed?

The original file is super huge, so I need this to be really efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I copy pasted larsks's response, but I have added the close line, to avoid the problem indicated in this post:  [gawk / awk: piping date to getline *sometimes* won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391272/gawk-awk-piping-date-to-getline-sometimes-wont-work)

```
awk '{
    tmp="echo " $2 " | openssl md5 | cut -f2 -d\" \""
tmp | getline cksum
close(tmp)
$2=cksum
print
}' < sample
```

Comment: That's passing the contents of `$2` to the shell unquoted so it's open to globbing, work splitting, malicious code injection, etc. (use `tmp="echo \047" $2 "\047...` instead) and is using `getline` in a way that'll quietly corrupt your output if it fails in any way, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to use `getline`.

Answer (score 5):

So, you don't really want to be doing this with `awk`.  Any of the popular high-level scripting languages -- Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. -- would do this in a way that was simpler and more robust.  Having said that, something like this will work.

Given input like this:

```
this is a test
```

(E.g., a row with four columns), we can replace a given column with its md5 checksum like this:

```
awk '{
    tmp="echo " $2 " | openssl md5 | cut -f2 -d\" \""
tmp | getline cksum
$2=cksum
print
}' < sample
```

This relies on GNU awk (you'll probably have this by default on a Linux system), and it uses `openssl` to generate the md5 checksum.  We first build a shell command line in `tmp` to pass the selected column to the `md5` command.  Then we pipe the output into the `cksum` variable, and replace column 2 with the checksum.  Given the sample input above, the output of this awk script would be:

```
this 7e1b6dbfa824d5d114e96981cededd00 a test
```

Comment: This is really the wrong sort of thing for awk. Your time would be better spent with one of the other languages I mentioned.

Comment: I see several problems with this solution.  For one thing, if the column (`$2`) contains shell meta-characters, it can do unexpected things.  Using single quotes doesn't entirely solve this (the field could contain single quotes itself).  And using `echo` rather than `echo -n` means that you'll get the md5sum of the field with a newline appended (`7e1b...` is the md5sum of `"is\n"`, not of `"is"`.)

Comment: With Perl, you can use a module that does md5 checksums without invoking an external program -- or, if you prefer, you can invoke an external program without going through the shell (`perldoc perlfunc` and search for "system").

Comment: ...and this is why I started out with (and followed up with) the fact that this problem isn't really something appropriate for awk.

Comment: This solution created defunct processes for each line processed.  Anyone know how to prevent that?

Comment: Found it.  https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html  You have to manually close the file

Answer (score 2):

This might work using Bash/GNU sed:

```
<<<"this is a test" sed -r 's/(\S+\s)(\S+)(.*)/echo "\1 $(md5sum <<<"\2") \3"/e;s/ - //'
this  7e1b6dbfa824d5d114e96981cededd00  a test
```

or a mostly sed solution:

```
<<<"this is a test" sed -r 'h;s/^\S+\s(\S+).*/md5sum <<<"\1"/e;G;s/^(\S+).*\n(\S+)\s\S+\s(.*)/\2 \1 \3/'
this 7e1b6dbfa824d5d114e96981cededd00 a test
```

Replaces `is` from `this is a test` with md5sum

Explanation:

In the first:- identify the columns and use back references as parameters in the Bash command which is substituted and evaluated then make cosmetic changes to lose the file description (in this case standard input) generated by the md5sum command.

In the second:- similar to the first but hive the input string into the hold space, then after evaluating the md5sum command, append the string `G` to the pattern space (md5sum result) and using substitution arrange to suit.

Comment: What is `'/e` in the first example ? Is it a sed flag ? I can't get it to work and get from by bash prompt: `sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: @martin the `e` flag on a substitution command is GNU specific and evaluates the pattern space (following substitution) as if it were in the current shell.

Comment: thanks but anyway, the error above still happen on my side with the first example you provided.

Comment: Well, on my host it seems the substitution runs in 'sh' rather than 'bash' for any reason, hence I issue the command from bash on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a better time with `read` than `awk`, though I haven't done any benchmarking.

the input (scratch001.txt):

```
foo|bar|foobar|baz|bang|bazbang
baz|bang|bazbang|foo|bar|foobar
```

transformed using `read`:

```
while IFS="|" read -r one fish twofish red fishy bluefishy; do
  twofish=`echo -n $twofish | md5sum | tr -d "  -"`
  echo "$one|$fish|$twofish|$red|$fishy|$bluefishy"
done < scratch001.txt
```

produces the output:

```
foo|bar|3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f|baz|bang|bazbang
baz|bang|19e737ea1f14d36fc0a85fbe0c3e76f9|foo|bar|foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that with perl :

```shell
echo "aze qsd wxc" | perl -MDigest::MD5 -ne 'print "$1 ".Digest::MD5::md5_hex($2)." $3" if /([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)/' 
aze 511e33b4b0fe4bf75aa3bbac63311e5a wxc
```

If you want to obfuscate large amount of data it might be faster than sed and awk which need to fork a md5sum process for each lines.