# Bash script writing 2 files with different output elements per input line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to use a bash script to process 1 input file into 2 output files, each containing the same number of lines as the input file but with different parts of the input line. In particular one of the output files has to contain a md5hash of a selection of the input line, (hash calculated per line, not per file!):

So

**Input_file.txt: ** 3 fields, separated by space**

```
12347654 abcdfg 1verylongalpha1234numeric1

34543673 nvjfur 2verylongalpha1234numeric2

75868643 vbdhde 3verylongalpha1234numeric3
```

**output file_1.txt would have to look like this:** (left field is MD5sum, right field is field3 from input file which is also contained in the MD5hash):

```
12df5j754G75f738fjk3483df3fdf9 1verylongalpha1234numeric1

3jf75j47fh4G84ka9J884hs355jhd8 2verylongalpha1234numeric2

4hf7dn46chG4875ldgkk348fk345d9 3verylongalpha1234numeric3
```

**output file_2.txt would have to look like this:** (field1 and field2 from input file + MD5HASH)

```
12347654 abcdfg 12df5j754G75f738fjk3483df3fdf9

34543673 nvjfur 3jf75j47fh4G84ka9J884hs355jhd8

75868643 vbdhde 4hf7dn46chG4875ldgkk348fk345d9
```

I already have a script that doesthe job but it performs very badly: (script below may not work, this is from the top of my head, no linux here where I write this, sorry)

```
#!/bin/bash

While read line

do   MD5_HASH=${sed -nr 's/^[[:digit:]]*\s[[:alpha:]]*\s([[:alnum:]]*)/\1/p' <<<$line     | md5sum} 
read $line DATA_PART1 DATA_PART2 DATA_PART3

echo "$MD5_HASH $DATA_PART3" >> file_1.txt    ##append file_2.txt in loop THIS IS WHERE IT GETS HORRIBLY SLOW!

echo "$DATA_PART1 $DATA_PART2 $MD5_HASH" 
done < input_file.txt > file_2.txt

exit 0
```

I think that the "redirect stdout to file with append construct" '>>' is responsible for the slow performance, but I can't think of another way. Its in the loop because I have to calculate the md5hash per line.

(and oh, the sed command is necessary because in reality the part that goes into the MD5SUM can only be captured with regex and a quite complex pattern)

So anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Your code is incomplete (the loop body is not closed with `done`). Please correct it and format the code as a code block, not as a quote (I already changed the formatting for you file samples, please do the same for code)

Comment: Lev, 'done' is there but hardly visible. I will try to format the codeblock. First timer for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one case in which I'd use a fully-featured language, such as Python.

Although you might find a way to do this by using only the standard gnu tools, you'd very likely end up with a solution that will be:

- very complex, hard to read and maintain
- inefficient, as the tools don't provide a straight-forward way to do this.

### 1. Creating the first file in Python

```
from hashlib import md5
with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for l in infile:
        if not l.strip(): continue
        parts = l.strip().split()
        print md5(parts[2]).hexdigest(), parts[2]
```

### 2. Creating the second file in Python

```
from hashlib import md5
with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for l in infile:
        if not l.strip(): continue
        parts = l.strip().split()
        print parts[0], parts[1], md5(parts[2]).hexdigest()
```

I'm not sure about on which fields you calculated the checksum; however, of course, you can calculate it on whichever field(s) you want; you could also perform more complex regexp-based matching on the lines; and you can speed up things by outputting the two files at once, thus avoiding calculating the md5 twice.

### 3. Creating the two files at once

```
from hashlib import md5
with open('infile.txt','r')  as infile, open('out1.txt','w') as out1, open('out2.txt','w') as out2:
    for l in infile:
        if not l.strip(): continue
        parts = l.strip().split()
        _checksum = md5(parts[2]).hexdigest()
        out1.write("%s\n" % " ".join([ _checksum, parts[2] ]))
        out2.write("%s\n" % " ".join([ parts[0], parts[1], _checksum ]))
```

### 4. Same as #1 but reading from standard input

```
import sys
from hashlib import md5
for l in sys.stdin:
    if not l.strip(): continue
    parts = l.strip().split()
    print md5(parts[2]).hexdigest(), parts[2]
```

Comment: Thanks, I do not know Python very well but in the solution(s) per file, where is the outfile declaration? Or would that be done outside the Python script like "#./python_script.py > outfile.txt"

Comment: yes, in the two "single" file solutions, all the output is written on the standard output; if you want to directly write to file, add an ``open('out1.txt','w') as out1`` in the with statement, as in the third example.

Comment: Thanks, I have fallen for Python. Will do a crash course on it because it looks pretty powerful to me.

Comment: Indeed it is.. if you are interested, on this month issue of linux journal http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/november-2012-issue-linux-journal-python there's an article dedicated specifically to replacing bash utility scripts with Python ones, that could be a good starting point..

Answer (score 2):

Your bash script can be tidied up a bit. Note that the `read` command can read the 3 fields into separate variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f file_1.txt file_2.txt    
While read f1 f2 f3; do
    hash=$(md5sum <<< $f3)
    printf "%s %s\n" "$hash" "$f3" >> file_1.txt
    printf "%s %s %s\n" "$f1" "$f2" "$hash" >> file_2.txt
done < input_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could not figure for which string you want to compute the md5, this one-liner does it on the whole line, and outputs the processed 'input_file' as you wish in 'file1' and 'file2':

```
awk '{ "md5 -q -s \""$0"\"" | getline md5; 
     print md5" "$3 > "file1"; 
     print $1" "$2" "md5 > "file2" }' input_file
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Note that using `getline` means awk is still forking out to an external process to compute each checksum, so this is not an efficiency win over the shell solutions.

Comment: I think you have to put 'openssl' in front of the 'md5' statement. like can be read in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024392/awk-replace-a-column-with-its-hash-value

Answer (score 0):

You can write both files at the same time from bash, like this:

```
; function to remove extraneous filename output from md5sum.  omit on 
; OS X, which has 'md5' command that already works this way.
md5() { set -- $(md5sum "$@"); echo "$1"; }

exec 3>file_1.txt 4>file_2.txt
while read left middle right; do
  md5="$(echo -n "$right" | md5)"
  echo >&3 "$md5 $right"
  echo >&4 "$left $middle $md5"
done <input_file.txt
exec 3>&- 4>&-
```

That assumes the simple whitespace-separated fields of your example; you would of course still have to do whatever `sed` magic is required to get the actual target for the MD5 sum.

It won't be very efficient, though.  For better performance, you should use something like Perl or Python, which can do both the field extraction you're using `sed` for and the MD5 calculation all within a single process that is also much faster than the shell at looping over lines of input.  Perl example:

```
perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -lane '
  BEGIN { open $f1, ">file_1.txt"; open $f2, ">file_2.txt" }
  $md5 = md5_hex $F[2];
  print $f1 "$md5 $F[2]";
  print $f2 "$F[0] $F[1] $md5";
' input_file.txt
```

Comment: Nice solution, although I did a quick benchmark on 10k lines (results here https://gist.github.com/4038697) and, as I guessed before, the Python solution was way much faster.. (65ms vs 12399ms..)

Comment: By the way, you should strip out the newline from the end of ``$right`` before calculating the checksum..

Comment: Yes, any solution that avoids forking a new copy of `md5sum` for every checksum calculation will be much faster.  But the performance, not the alleged complexity, is the reason to switch languages.  It's still pretty easy in bash - just slow.  :) The newline is a good point, edited.

Comment: I was thinking of awk, but I'm not sure whether it has anything to calculate md5; it would be perfect if so.. spawning a process per row is ok only for very small amounts of rows, then it gets terribly inefficient.

Comment: yeah, you'll want to use perl (or python or ruby or ...) if you want performance.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to increase the efficiency with pipes and parallel.

According to your pseudo-code, you want the md5 sum of the last element:

```
paste -d ' '     \
  input_file.txt \
  <(cut -d' ' -f3 input_file.txt | parallel echo '{}' \| md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1) |
  awk '{ print $4, $3 > "file_1.txt"; print $1, $2, $4 > "file_2.txt" }'
```

#### Explanation

The md5 sum is calculated in parallel in the process substitution, the output from here is "pasted" onto the original file. Finally awk takes care of placing the output into the correct files.

#### Edit

I agree with *redShadow* that this will never be very efficient in shell, as you need to 
sub-shell a lot. Here's an alternative in perl:

*split.pl*

```perl
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
use v5.10;

open O1, ">file_1.txt" or die $!; open O2, ">file_2.txt" or die $!;

$, = " ";

while(<>) { chomp; 
  @F = split / +/;
  $md5 = md5_hex $F[2];
  say O1 $md5, $F[2];
  say O2 @F[0,1], $md5;
}
close O1; close O2;
```

Run like this:

```
<input_file.txt perl split.pl
```

Output in both cases:

*file_1.txt*

```
765ac5d0002aed1141a6a4e7b90e4ac9 1verylongalpha1234numeric1
b31901def07d436aed2c8028b2efa4ec 2verylongalpha1234numeric2
0722a6e50f6f8726f9754e7f71f9ad2c 3verylongalpha1234numeric3
```

*file_2.txt*

```
12347654 abcdfg 765ac5d0002aed1141a6a4e7b90e4ac9
34543673 nvjfur b31901def07d436aed2c8028b2efa4ec
75868643 vbdhde 0722a6e50f6f8726f9754e7f71f9ad2c
```

Comment: I like your bash alternative. Decided to go for the Python option and performance though