# Add an md5 hash value to a big CSV file

Tags: csv, hash, awk, sed

I need to insert a new field containing the MD5 Hash value of the first field for each line of an 80 GB csv file.

For small projects, I have been able to do this in excel by passing the field value to

```
=WEBSERVICE(CONCATENATE("https://helloacm.com/api/md5/?s="&ENCODEURL(A1)))
```

However, with the 80 GB file, that is not an option.

Via AWK, is it possible to pull the first field of each row in this massive csv, calculate the md5 for the content of the first field, and insert that value back into the same line?

Example line:

Original:

```
"value001","value002","Value003","Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"
```

Revised Example line with md5ofvalue001 field inserted:

```
"value001","MD5ofValue001","value002","Value003","Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"
```

Comment: Dup?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024392/awk-replace-a-column-with-its-hash-value

Comment: @shawnt00 yes, it's a duplicate question but the selected answer in that question is wrong so idk if closing this as a duplicate of that would be useful.

Comment: @shawnt100 - Also, the selected answer there uses awk, which is ridiculously slow for this type of task for files with a very large number of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` is great, but for your problem, it will probably be much too slow if you have to use system() to calculate the md5.  `awk` may also be poorly suited to the task if the first field has any embedded commas.

In any case, here is a fast (or at least much faster) solution using `php`, which I've found to have excellent support for CSV of various stripes and hues.  You should be able to run this as a script on a Mac or Linux-like platform.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

# Syntax: $0 [PATHNAME]
# A filter that expects its input to have the CSV format.
# Input is taken from STDIN if PATHNAME is - or not specified.
# Output is the same CSV but with the md5 of the first field tacked on.

$file = ($argc > 1 && $argv[1] != "" ) ? $argv[1] : 'php://stdin';
if ( $file == "-" ) { $file = 'php://stdin'; }

$handle = @fopen($file, "r");
$sep = ",";

if ($handle) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $sep)) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $data[] = md5($data[0]);
    fputcsv(STDOUT, $data, $sep);
  }
  fclose($handle);
} else {
  echo "{$argv[0]}: unable to fopen $argv[1]\n";
  exit(1);
}
?>
```

If you want to leave the input lines unaltered, then you could read in the line literally and use str_getcsv() to parse it, etc.

Comment: I have done very little with PHP however, I gave this a go and it gave me the unable to open file error.

Comment: @trackthis - Sorry - the comments were in the wrong place. Fixed.

Comment: Peak, this is achieving exactly the calculation that I was hoping to get. However, two issues remain:
1. Most of my 20 or so fields on the output from this script, including the first field and the new md5 field do not have their " text qualifiers.
2. In this script can I pipe to another csv vs printing directly to the terminal window?

Comment: (1) If the quotation marks are not included, they are not necessary for the CSV to be valid. If you want to replicate the input, I'd suggest computing the md5 sums for the column of interest, and then pasting the original file with these md5 sums (e.g. using the `paste` command). Or you could write your own fputcsv() :-)  (2) To redirect the output to a file, the simplest would be to use ">" (e.g. SCRIPTNAME inpathname > outpathname).

Comment: Though this solution for my problem was not the use of AWK. I did arrive at the right solution given the size of the file I was manipulating.

Comment: @trackthis - I added a paragraph about str_getcsv().

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

Here is a proof of concept for you

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q='\"' '{
         cmd= "echo " $1 " | md5sum | cut -f1 -d\" \""; 
         (cmd | getline md5); print $1, q md5 q}' file

"value001","c36a5b774bfb2fd236331ac5ebef4266"
```

Comment: This solution looks like it could achieve the desired result however, it resulted in the example you gave and did not contain the other fields from the CSV for each line. Using awk how would I include them? e.g. using your example:
"value001","c36a5b774bfb2fd236331ac5ebef4266","value002","Value003","Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"

Comment: well, that's why I called it proof of concept.  If you insist `$1=$1 OFS q md5 q; print` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how to do it in awk, and assuming that `echo val | md5sum` is how to calculate an "md5sum", this is the awk script to do that:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    cmd = "echo " $1 " | md5sum"
    if ( (cmd | getline md5) > 0 ) {
        sub(/ .*/,"",md5)
    }
    else {
        printf "Warning: Failed to calculate md5sum of %s at input line %d\n", $1, NR | "cat>&2"
        md5 = "N/A"
    }
    close(cmd)
    $1 = $1 OFS "\"" md5 "\""
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"value001","c36a5b774bfb2fd236331ac5ebef4266","value002","Value003","Value004","Value005","Value006","Value007"
```

As noted elsewhere, since you're jumping in and out of shell every line this will be slow compared to a tool that can do md5sum calculations internally.