# searching .CSV file with AWK - only working with first row

Tags: csv, unix, ubuntu, awk

I've been trying to search through a specific column of a .csv file to find cells containing a particular word. However, it's only working for the first row (i.e. the headings) in my .csv file.

The file is a series of over 10,000 forum posts, with column 1 as the post key and column 2 as the post text. The headings as below are 'key', 'annotated sentence'.

```
key,annotated sentence
"(212, 2)","Got evidence to back that up??

I'm not sure how a stoner's worse than an alcoholic really.

-Wez"
"(537, 5)","Forgive me for laughing; no, not really ha, ha, ha ha ha
Could it be that people here as well as Canada and the rest of the world has figured out your infantile ""grading system of States"" is a complete sham and your very reason for existing is but an anti-constitutional farce and has lost any claims you have or will make? You stand alone now brady, with simply a few still clinging to the false hope of having others pay for your failures and unConstitutional stance so you can sit on your hands while you keep harping on overturning the 2A."
"(595, 0)",So you're actually claiming that it is a lie to say that the UK has a lower gun crime rate than the US? Even if the police were miscounting crimes it's still a huge and unjustified leap in logic to conclude from that that the UK does not have a lower gun crime rate.
"(736, 3)","The anti-abortionists claim a load of **** on many issues. I don't listen to them. To put the ""life"" of an unfertilized egg above that of a person is grotesquely sick IMO. I support any such stem cell research wholeheartedly."
```

The CSV separator is a comma, and the text delimiter is ".

if I try:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /key/ {print}' posts_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

it will output the headings row no problem. However, I have tried:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /212/ {print}' posts_file.csv > output_file.csv
awk -F, '$2 ~ /Canada/ {print}' posts_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

and neither of these work - no matches are found though there should be. I can't figure out why? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `awk` cannot properly parse CSV data with double-quoted fields containing embedded commas, unfortunately; your best bet is to find a CSV parser.

Comment: @mklement0 ah, thanks anyway!

Comment: GNU `awk` can be made to parse CSV data with double quoted fields containing embedded commas (see [How can I read a CSV file if only non-empty fields are wrapped by double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507866/) for example), though it isn't easy. However, even that has problems with newlines in double quoted fields — there isn't a simple way to handle that because `awk` reads lines and doesn't know how to read multiple lines and isn't easily trained to do better.  So, although I mildly disagree with the initial comment by mkelement0, the advice ("use a CSV parser") is correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: So I guess the correct statement is: _one flavor_ of Awk can do it (_GNU_ Awk, using _field_-matching variable `FPAT`, as demonstrated in your linked answer), and only (reasonably so) if (double-quoted) fields have no embedded newlines. Use a CSV parser otherwise.

Comment: @mklement0: Yes, that's a fair summary.  I don't know if I could be bothered to try to create a regex that would spot that the last field of a line is incomplete and therefore read more lines until it is complete, and then worry about splitting it with FPAT, etc.  At that point, you are almost certainly better off with a CSV parser rather than just `awk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's CSV parsing supports your format out of the box.

Below is a simple script that you could call as follows:

```
# csvfilter <1-basedFieldNdx> <regexStr> < <infile> > <outfile>
csvfilter 1 'key' < posts_file.csv > output_file.csv
csvfilter 1 '212' < posts_file.csv > output_file.csv
csvfilter 2 'Canada' < posts_file.csv > output_file.csv
```

Sample script `csvfilter`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import csv, sys, re

# Assign arguments to variables.
fieldNdx = int(sys.argv[1]) - 1  # Index of field to filter; Python arrays are 0-based!
reStr = sys.argv[2] if (len(sys.argv) > 2) else '' # Filter regex

# Read from stdin...
reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
# ... write to stdout.
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, reader.dialect)

# Read each line...
for row in reader:
  # Match the target field against the filter regex and
  # print the row only if it matches.  
  if (re.search(reStr, row[fieldNdx])):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

In general complex csv doesn't work but in your case since key and annotated sentence have very distinct value types you can extend your pattern search to the whole record instead of key and value, the trick is defining the record, which again based on your format can be done as well.  For example

```
$ awk -v RS='\n"' '/Canada/{print RT $0}' csv    

"(537, 5)","Forgive me for laughing; no, not really ha, ha, ha ha ha
Could it be that people here as well as Canada and the rest of the world has figured out your infantile ""grading syst
em of States"" is a complete sham and your very reason for existing is but an anti-constitutional farce and has lost a
ny claims you have or will make? You stand alone now brady, with simply a few still clinging to the false hope of havi
ng others pay for your failures and unConstitutional stance so you can sit on your hands while you keep harping on ove
rturning the 2A."
```

and this

```
$ awk -v RS='\n"' '/(212, 2)/{print RT $0}' csv       

"(212, 2)","Got evidence to back that up??

I'm not sure how a stoner's worse than an alcoholic really.

-Wez"
```

Answer (score 0):

[OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) could help with the search.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use awk safely with complex CSV is to use a "csv2tsv" utility to convert the CSV file to a format that can be handled properly by awk.
Usually the TSV ("tab-separated values") format is just right for the job.

(If the final output must be CSV, then either a complementary "tsv2csv" utility can be used, or awk itself can do the job -- though some care may be required to get it exactly right.)

So the pipeline might look like this:

```
csv2tsv < input.csv | awk -F\\t 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} ....' | tsv2csv
```

There are several alternatives for csv-to-tsv conversion, ranging from roll-your-own scripts to Excel, but I'd recommend taking the time to check that whichever tool or toolset you select satisfies the "edge case" requirements that are of interest to you.

Comment: Interesting: there are versions of `csv2tsv` in C, Ruby, Python and JavaScript at minimum (Google search on 'csv2tsv').  Which variant were you using?

Comment: I've used many of them (including some you didn't mention, e.g. the one in the tsvutils package, and a node.js implementation), but before many of these were available, I wrote a simple script in PHP, which has a very trustworthy and flexible implementation.  I posted a variant in connection with a slightly different problem here on SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372642/add-an-md5-hash-value-to-a-big-csv-file/35383148#35383148